# JW Player как использовать свой скин?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, видео

Помогите разобраться с JW Player. Мне нужно немного его стилизовать для своих целей.

В интернете нарыл не так много (по я так понимаю последний, 7й версии) информации.

Код выглядит так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
            'playlist': [{
              'sources': [
                {
                  'file': 'it.mp4'
                }
              ]
            }],
            'width': 480,
            'height': 320,
            skin: "myskinfile.css"
        });
    });
```

Как я понял в skin: "myskinfile.css" должны лежать мои стили:

```
button{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Никакие элементы не реагируют. Если вставить стили в html - аналогично.

```
#body .jw_modified .jw-skin-seven .jw-display-icon-container  {
width: 110px;
border-radius: 10%;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: blue;
}
```

Расскажите, как мне изменить стиль плеера?

Answer (score 1):

API сейчас и доки имеются практически на всех сервисах
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/css-skinning-reference.html

Comment: первый пример я и взял с их сайта. Я не могу понять где ошибка...

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

1) скиньте ссылку на свой скин, может смогу сразу сказать что в нем не так

2) есть [референс](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_reference/) по созданию скинов, там вроде все точно написано какие элементы зачем нужны

3) как вариант можете скачать один из родных скинов и в нем сделать все изменения. например вот есть [пример на гитхабе](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/tree/2d59678c4cc70fb8c98b05dfcea24e8a95d0dab0/test/manual/css-skins/css)